# Place coordinates halfway (or 75%, etc) up the plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using this macro

```
\newcommand{\ymax}[0]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}}
```

to do stuff like the following:

```
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, \ymax);
```

and this works fine.

However, if I want to do something like `\ymax / 2` or `0.5 * \ymax`, this doesn't work. I get the error, "Could not parse input ' 0.5 * 1.09763666e6' as a floating point number, sorry."

Do I need to use something like `\pgfmathparse`? What is the correct way to do arithmetic on this value?

When I change the expression to

```
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, \pgfmathparse{0.5*\ymax});
```

then my TeX Live freezes and I have to `^C` out.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]

\newcommand{\getpgfkey}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/#1}}
\newcommand{\ymax}[0]{\getpgfkey{ymax}}
\newcommand{\ymin}[0]{\getpgfkey{ymin}}

\addplot [smooth, domain=0:6] (x, x); % to generate an axis cs

% this works fine
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:2, \ymin) -- (axis cs:2, \ymax);

% none of these work
%\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, \ymax / 2);
%\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, (\ymax / 2));
%\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, ({\ymax / 2}));
%\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, {(\ymax / 2)});
%\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, (0.5*\ymax));
%\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, (0.5*{\ymax}));
%\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, {0.5*(\ymax});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input ' {0.5*6.0e0}' as a floating po
int number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '*6.0e0'..

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

Comment: Can you draw a mockup of what you want?

Comment: Didn't test it but try putting them first in extra parentheses and then braces. that should signal tikz to parse it as math. Emphasis on *should* :)

Comment: @percusse Using `at (axis cs:4, ({\ymax / 2}))` I get `Could not parse input ' ({3.3075714e6/ 2}'` ; is the lack of space between `e6` and `/` contributing to the problem?

Comment: @WChargin The other way around. parentheses inside braces

Comment: @percusse oh... but `at (axis cs:4,{(\ymax / 2)})` still yields `Could not parse input '(3.3075714e6/ 2)'` as a floating point number... am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think so. I have to test what I'm talking about before I claim anything. I'll check and fix an answer if I can soon.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I create a test document, everything works fine. What version of PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: I have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}`; could you share your test document?

Comment: @WChargin: I think it would be a better idea if you could edit your question to include a minimal example document that reproduces the error you encounter. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question and my test document isn't actually relevant.

Comment: @WChargin could you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) as Jake requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the extra parentheses; for example, instead of :

```
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, (\ymax / 2));
```

use simply

```
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, \ymax / 2);
```

This works using `pgfplots 2013/10/03 v1.9`. The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false]

\newcommand{\getpgfkey}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/#1}}
\newcommand{\ymax}[0]{\getpgfkey{ymax}}
\newcommand{\ymin}[0]{\getpgfkey{ymin}}

\addplot [smooth, domain=0:6] (x, x); % to generate an axis cs

% this works fine
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:2, \ymin) -- (axis cs:2, \ymax);

% these work
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4, \ymax / 2);
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:4.5, \ymin) -- (axis cs:4.5, {\ymax / 4});
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:5, \ymin) -- (axis cs:5, {3*\ymax / 4});
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:3.5, \ymin) -- (axis cs:3.5, 0.666*\ymax);
\draw[dashed] (axis cs:5.5, \ymin) -- (axis cs:5.5, {0.333*\ymax});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...I don't see what you've changed, and your example doesn't work for me. Could you please elaborate? I get the error: "Could not parse input ' 6.0e0/ 2' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '/ 2 '.."

Comment: @WChargin I removed some extra pair of parentheses. As my image shows, the code I posted works OK. If it is not working for you, perhaps you are using an old version of `pgfplots`?

Comment: I'm using "Package: pgfplots 2013/03/17 v1.8 Data Visualization (1.8-3-gaf58a29)" (as reported by `\listfiles`); is this out of date?

Comment: (not using parentheses was the first thing I tried; I included parentheses in the MWE because of the comments on my question)

Comment: @WChargin It's outdated. I'm using `pgfplots 2013/10/03 v1.9 Data Visualization (1.9)`. Try updating and it should work without the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks. (It might be helpful to add something to your answer along those lines.) Unfortunately I can't update because I'm running my system off a flash drive with casper-rw and the package manager is flaky; if I `apt-get update` it nukes my system and I have to create a new image. But thanks for your help.

Comment: @WChargin Yes, I've added some remark about this.